# Not storing this message in Datastore, missingAttributeNames

Tags: amazon-web-services, transform, iot, pipeline, aws-iot-analytics

I got this error from AWS IoT Analytics service after message is Transform in lambda:
my lambda get as input a json format string

```
{
"id": "223",
"data": "valid-timestamp,1,2,3,4,5"
}
```

The data key holds my IoT data values on a specific timespan

The lambda parse the above input and return array of dict:

```
[
   {
       "id": "1",
       "timestamp": "valid-timestamp1",
        "value-1": "1",
        "value-2": "2",
         "value-3": "3"
   },
   {
       "id": "1",
         "timestamp": "valid-timestamp1",
        "value-1": "1",
        "value-2": "2",
         "value-3": "3"
   }
]
```

I did not succeeded to create a my_data_store
I would be happy if someone can assist.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IoT Analytics doesn't support hyphens '-' in attribute names. If you want to use a separator, try using an underscore instead '_' and that should resolve your problem.